# Как делается анимация персонажей в игре?

Tags: разработка-игр, анимация

Уже год пытаюсь сделать движение человечка (хотя бы ходьбу) (в двумерном пространстве и использую открытый физ. движок Box2D), но не могу никак понять, как это сделать. Часто задавал подобные вопросы на других форумах, на что мне отвечали либо "иди рисуй спрайты и не приставай с глупыми вопросами", либо "ну это делают с помощью motion-capture". Ни прямых рук, чтобы нарисовать спрайты, ни технологии motion-capture у меня под рукой нету. Поэтому очень надеюсь услышать толковый ответ по данной теме здесь.

*И сопутствующий вопрос: как в таких играх, как assassin's creed (3 и более поздние части) или gta 4 (5) создали такую анимацию ходьбы, что персонажи могут спокойно передвигаться по лестницам или по наклонным плоскостям? Это ведь явно сделано не па заготовкам, а рассчитывается в реальном времени, так как же они это сделали ?!*

Comment: Думаю там как раз mc, движением человека управляет сотня мышц которые приделаны к сотне костей. Кроме того еще и мозг вмешивается. Без захвата естественно не получается. (Можно еще вручную рисовать как дисней раньше)

Comment: Поищите про генетические алгоритмы, artifical evolution – эти технологии применяются для создания [убедительных](https://vimeo.com/109169719) в поведении с любыми препятствиями персонажей. Еще в фильме 2010 года «The Secret Life of Chaos» (очень вдохновляет!) отлично об этом рассказывают. По-русски: [Тайная жизнь хаоса](http://kinozal.tv/details.php?id=598567).

Comment: [![введите сюда описание изображения](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yU366.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yU366.png)Посмотри вот тут
https://github.com/Ninja-action/worck
https://github.com/korolariya/Ninja-Action
Один из них должен работать
http://pixijs.github.io/examples/

Comment: в GTA 5 применяется Euphoria - это программный движок анимации персонажей

Answer (score 13):

## "КТО ВИНОВАТ?"

### 1. Покадровая анимация

Обычно используется в 2d играх. Допустим, если нужно сделать анимацию ходьбы персонажа, то рисуется несколько изображений персонажа в разных стадиях движения. Потом в игре эти кадры переключаются с каким-то интервалом времени. Профит.

Подобный подход подразумевает довольно большой объем работы художника. Motion Capture тут никак не прикрутишь. Но художник, естественно, может использовать снимки людей и животных в разных фазах движения в качестве референсов.

С технической стороны обычно предъявляются следующие требования (так с кадрами удобнее работать): изображения должны обладать прозрачным фоном, между кадрами должен быть один и тот же интервал времени, анимация должна быть "на месте" (движение персонажа обычно осуществляется программно), не должно быть необходимости сдвигать кадры один относительно другого.

Далее действия разнятся в зависимости от игрового движка и желания левой пятки программиста. Но чаще всего изображения собираются в [атлас](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81) (также их называют spritesheet), который состоит из картинки со множеством кадров + описания координат кадров в этой картинке (и их названий), которое может быть прочитано движком.

Пример:

[image: Пример атласа с покадровой анимацией персонажа]
<sub>(источник: [opengameart.org](http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/Hero_0.png))</sub>

(взято с [opengameart.org](http://opengameart.org/content/base-character-spritesheet-16x16), лицензия [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/choose/zero/)):

**В 2d покадровые анимации - практически единственный способ сделать реалистичную анимацию персонажа.**

А вот **движение**, **поворот**, **изменение размера** - эти анимации обычно делаются программно. Думаю, нетрудно догадаться, что со всех сторон намного выгоднее двигать персонажа из кода, чем рисовать все его движение с отступом от начальной точки.

Но, таким же образом можно и полноценно анимировать персонажа!

### 2. Скелетная анимация в 2d

Если нарисовать его не целиком, а сделать его состоящим из отдельных частей (руки, ноги, тело и т.п.), то каждую из частей можно двигать относительно другой, и получить в результате анимированного персонажа.

Подобная техника использована, например, в [проекте](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11228), демонстрировавшем 2d возможности движка [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/ru/), когда они в нем только появились. Персонаж состоит из отдельных частей, которые движутся относительно друг друга при помощи различных средств анимации движка. *При запуске в последних версиях Unity может потребоваться доработка проекта напильником.*

**Скелетная анимация** является развитием этой идеи. Персонаж все так же разделяется на части. Только теперь эти части привязаны к костям некоего скелета и движутся вместе с ними. Как это работает, очень хорошо видно в [промо-ролике Spine](https://youtu.be/5RTkImAOJKM) (на всякий случай, предупреждаю, что Spine - платная система).

Тем не менее, применять Motion Capture к персонажам созданным таким образом будет не более чем освоением бюджета. 100% Реалистичности все равно добиться не удастся (ибо 2d), а среднестатистический 2d-художник/аниматор сделает все быстрее, дешевле и лучше.

Но, по факту, отличие от анимирования отдельных частей тела "вручную" только в более удобном инструменте для создания анимаций.

А вот отличия от покадровых анимаций - значительные. Плюсы скелетной 2d анимации - в намного меньшем объеме текстур (на ПК это уже почти не имеет значения, а вот на мобильных плафтормах - еще какое), в намного меньшем количестве работы художника (рисовать нужно не 100500 кадров одного персонажа, а всего лишь несколько частей тела) и в возможности переноса анимаций между персонажами с одинаковым скелетом. Минус - в меньшей реалистичности.

### 3. Скелетная анимация в 3d

В 3d все немного не так. Персонаж является объемной моделью, которая на части не делится (но может и делиться, если нужно). При анимации скелета - происходит деформация сетки модели. Для того, чтобы понять, увидеть и пощупать, как все это создается и работает, могу порекомендовать [вот этот туториал](http://zakjr.com/blog/blender-to-unity-workflow-part-1/) (на английском) по созданию персонажа в [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) и импорту его в Unity.

Для персонажей с одинаковым скелетом анимация тут так же может быть общей. В том же Unity, например, есть Mecanim Humanoid Rig. В результате чего можно купить/сделать/скачать бесплатно готовую анимацию и применять ее к любым гуманоидным персонажам (естественно, и персонажи, и анимации должны быть созданы и настроены определенным образом).

Анимации могут создаваться как моделлером, так и отдельным аниматором, в том числе и при помощи Motion Capture. Собственно, после получения mocap-данных с реального человека (этот процесс, думаю, должен быть понятен) они дорабатываются напильником и превращаются в обычные анимации. Плюс, конечно, очевиден - анимации становятся более реалистичными. Проблемы тут в том, что реалистичность хороша далеко не всегда, и в том, что аниматор сам вручную зачастую сделает лучше, быстрее и дешевле.

Кроме вышеописанного, стоит упомянуть про [Ragdoll](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragdoll-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Суть заключается в том, что к костям скелета вместо анимации применяется физика, вследствие чего персонаж может более "реалистично" (с точки зрения физики) падать, умирать и т.п. Ragdoll, кстати, бывает и в 2d, но это редкость.

*А в связи с сопутствующим вопросом, обращу внимание на [IK (Inverse Kinematics)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) - весьма вероятно, что в указанных играх использовалось именно оно. Но, вообще, это просто мое предположение, свечку при разработке этих игр я не держал.*

## ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?

Что делать, если Вы не художник, и не аниматор, и не моделлер, и не т.п.

1. Найти художника/моделлера бесплатно (тогда Вам на gamedev.ru).
2. Найти художника/моделлера за деньги (Вам на биржи фриланса).
3. Найти результаты работы художника моделлера бесплатно (начните с opengameart.org, а так же загляните в магазины и на форумы популярных игровых движков - там немало бесплатных спрайтов и моделей).
4. Найти результаты работы художника/моделлера за деньги (в магазины популярных движков, или просто в онлайн-магазины текстур и 3d моделей, но в последних будьте внимательны - не все модели оптимизированы для игр).

**Будьте внимательны с лицензиями! Многие "свободные" лицензии имеют требования, выполнение которых может оказаться невозможно в проекте! Проприетарные - тем более!**

5. Научиться и сделать все самостоятельно. Руки выпрямляются при большом желании и усидчивости. Другое дело, что профессионалы в своей области сделают все "прямо сейчас".
6. Проявить креативность и упростить персонажа так, чтобы даже Вы могли нарисовать анимации для него.
7. Проявить еще больше креативности: взять персонажа в 3d (его найти бесплатно намного проще, чем покадровые анимации персонажей для 2d игр), наделать его скриншотов с нужного ракурса с нужной анимацией. Профит.

*P.S. В качестве бонуса - [Carnegie Mellon University Motion Capture Database](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/). Она же, конвертированная для Unity: [1](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19991), [2](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20282), [3](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20285). Бесплатно.*

Answer (score 2):

AC, GTA - это всё Motion Capture. Но наверняка типовые сцены - бег, ходьба, прыжок и т.п. на это всё есть уже типовые библиотеки. Кастомные сцены - дополнительно снимаются.

Если вы думаете что если какой-то магический алгоритм который позволит без прямых рук или motion capture хорошо нарисовать и анимировать, то вынужден вас расстроить. Ближайшая остановка - взять готовый спрайтшит или найти аниматора.

Если хотите заморочится возьмите знакомого, видеокамеру и снимите анимацию сами. Раньше разработчики примерно так и делали (1980-1990 годы).